# Odoo doesn't like the times I report to hr.attendance

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

I am reporting check_in and check_out events to the hr.attendance model via xmlrpc, and I think I am reporting correct times, for example:

```
ID: 75 Scan Type: check_in   Scan Time: 2022-06-22 14:14:57
ID: 75 Scan Type: check_out  Scan Time: 2022-06-22 22:55:12
```

Those times are in UTC, and when I look at the first attendance record (which gets accepted), it shows the correct local time (which in my case is 7:14am).

However, when the check_out event is reported, Odoo is returning:

```
[faultCode] => 2
[faultString] => "Check Out" time cannot be earlier than "Check In" time.
```

It’s definitely around ~8 hours later, from 14:14:57 to 22:55:12.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: Thank you @paxmees - I can't upvote your answer but that was the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

`check_in` and `check_out` should be on the same record.
First, you are creating a `check_in` record, and then you are probably trying to create a second record for `check_out`.
Instead, you should try to find the last open record and update the `check_out`.